# How to put Floating Action Button in the bottom of the screen with Collapsing ToolBar to be always visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have fragment with floating action button inside activity with collapsing toolbar. When toolbar is collapsed everything is ok, but when it's expended, FAB is not visible (it's below the screen).
Here is xml of my fragment with FAB:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you can try removing line 
app:layout_anchor="@+id/layout"

Comment: It doesn't work. Now FAB is in top-left of the layout

Comment: where is the code for toolbar, are your toolbar and fab in different xml?

Comment: also it would be better if you use recyclerview in place of listview.

Comment: Yes, i will change listview to recyclerview. Toolbar is in activity's xml, this is fragment's xml

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @alosdev put FAB to activity's layout and show it when it's needed

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
app:layout_anchor="@+id/layout"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
```

with

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
```

This should work

Comment: No, it doesn't work with collapsing toolbar. I have an idea to put FAB to activity xml. I will try it

Comment: Yeah please try